# Exploring Key Missing Concepts to Expand the OpenVINO C Library on GitHub

Tags: openvino

I'm seeking advice on resolving a challenging issue I'm encountering. Despite having most components in place, I'm struggling to pinpoint what's missing. Your insights would be invaluable.

The specific issue I'm encountering is outlined in [OpenVINO issue 22001](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/issues/22001)

Up to now, I've delved into these fundamental areas:

- Model Loading and Management

- Inference

- Device Agnosticism

- Synchronous and Asynchronous Inference

- Memory Management

- Pre- and Post-Processing

Any recommendations or insights on how to proceed would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Good first issues are issues that require developers to contribute in solving complex tasks. This is an initiative by OpenVINO™ GitHub organization to pull all the resources available via GitHub for the betterment of OpenVINO™ community. Therefore, we strongly encourage you to share your feedback/work progress in the same GitHub thread: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/issues/22001